# Can't insert a into DATETIME column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO sales SET store_id = ..., startDate = '2014-11-01 24:59:00', expireDate = '2014-11-01 24:59:00', …
```

The query works (i.e., the insert succeeds), but the startDate and expireDate columns (type 'DateTime') are filled as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. Why would this be?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no time like 24:59:00. Enter a correct time and try again. You get zeroes because you provided an illegal datetime.

Comment: D'oh!…mistake in the PHP logic there--tnx! Didn't realize it caught 'impossible times' like that...